# Removing objects that contains specified content from NSArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsdictionary

I have an `NSMutableArray` that contains `PNMessage` objects, all of them stores an `NSDictionary` object and some properties (date, channel). I would like to remove all objects from the array where the value of `keyR` and `keyS` equals with `someString` (inside the same object).

```
{\n    keyMessage = Lorem ipsum;\n    keyR = someString;\n    keyS = someString;\n}, date: (null), channel: sampple>",
```

I tried to make an enumeration, but i can't run it. I know it's wrong that i'm using dictionary keys with NSArray, but i don't had a better idea. So i would really appreciate, if somebody could help me.

```
  self.messagesArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:message];
  NSLog(@"mutable messages: %@", self.messagesArray);

  NSMutableArray *objectsToRemove = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

        for (NSArray *messageObject in self.messagesArray) {
            if ([messageObject[@"keyS"] isEqual:someString] && [messageObject[@"keyR"] isEqual:someString]) {
                [objectsToRemove addObject:messageObject];
            }
        }

        if ([objectsToRemove count]>0) {
            [self.messagesArray removeObjectsInArray:objectsToRemove];
            NSLog(@"deleted: %@", objectsToRemove);
        }

    }];
```

Comment: Remember that you can't remove an element from an object that's being enumerated.  The solution to that is to do `for (int i = array.length -1; i >= 0; i--) { examine array and conditionally remove element i }`.  Iterating explicitly and backwards keeps things from getting balled up.

Comment: There are some issues here, and some missing information. Right off the bat, you are iterating through `self.messagesArray` and casting each element to an `NSArray`, then trying to subscript them with an object (which is used on dictionaries, not arrays). I suspect that even that is incorrect though, as you as the elements are a different object type (`PNMessage`).

Comment: @Dima it's possible to filter with some basic method the objects in the array, that contain this exact string : `keyR = someString;\n    keyS = someString;\n` and remove them from the self.messagesArray?

Comment: @HotLicks if i make a copy from the self.messagesArray and remove the enumerated objects from the copy, it could work?

Comment: @sabin make a copy and enumerate through that, but remove objects from the original collection.

Comment: Yeah, that and variations will work, but the reverse `for` loop is simpler and faster, at least for simple cases.

Comment: @Dima possibly could you make a sample code, that shows how should i filter the objects that contains the desired strings inside the array?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do this is to filter using `-filteredArrayUsingPredicate:` on `NSArray`. As mentioned in the comments to your question it looks like you are trying to use dictionary subscripting on arrays which won't work but guessing that might be only in your example.

```
NSPredicate *filterPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:^BOOL(id obj, NSDictionary *bindings) {
    PNMessage *message = (PNMessage *)obj;
    if ([message.dict[@"keyS"] isEqualToString:someString] || [message.dict[@"keyR"] isEqualToString:someString]) {
        return NO;
    }

    return YES;
}

self.messagesArray = [messages filteredArrayUsingPredicate:filterPredicate];
```

Comment: In the last line it's not message instead of messages?